# Corporate Finance introduction and mentoring for Non-Finance - topics to focus on?

Tags: finance, corporate-finance

I work for an international engineering company and have been in an engineering position for 10+ years. As part of the career development I have expressed interest to learn more about the finance side of the business and arranged to have mentoring from the Finance department.

What topics should I focus on and suggest to cover? We did quickly cover balance sheet and P&L from annual report. For next step they told me I should drive the conversation (mentoring) and ask whatever I'm interested in. However, since I have no experience in the domain, I don't know what to ask or focus on.

Can you please suggest some topics from the Corporate Finance we could cover and would be interesting to know and understand for Non-Finance people. I do not plan to change my career, but get a better a understanding on the Finance. Thanks

Comment: I feel like your mentors are much better suited to have this same conversation with you than some random people from the internet...? It will definitely be a back and forth, with prompts on your part like "I want to study something interesting" or "I once read this in a report and did not understand what it meant", or " I am interested in finance because..." but these should get you going.

Comment: @Giskard yes ideally... it is more of a coaching than mentoring as it is different department (finance and engineering) and as mentioned in the introduction, they said I should drive the conversation and ask what I would like to know. To be honest, apart from balance sheet and P&L account not sure what to do more... it is a big area so I don't want to spend time on understanding e.g. accruals if this is not needed for corporate finance literacy and eventually not needed for any engineering management positions. Most of CEOs and executives in my industry come from engineering.

Comment: So let them know you have managerial ambitions and would like an intro to MBA?

Comment: tried, no budget for me :( .. and others (high-achievers) are already on the MBA path... So I was thinking, why not use the benefit of working in a big company by have some finance coaching (1 hour ever 1 or 2 months) on the interesting finance topics. I am sure engineering managers do not go into details of adding each expense or preparing quarterly reports, but they have some finance knowledge --> second best option if no MBA